# ANDROID STUDIO >> Sql Listview

Tags: java, android

I have this code which displays the content of the JOUEUR column.

This table has other columns, but I do not know how to display the column _ID next to the JOUEUR name

```
private void show_tab() {
    helper = new TaskDBHelper(ValiderJoueurs.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(Round.TABLE,
            new String[]{Playas.Columns._ID, Playas.Columns.JOUEUR, Playas.Columns.PLACE},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.players_view,
            cursor,
            new String[]{Playas.Columns.JOUEUR},
            new int[]{R.id.nomdujoueur},
            0
    );
    this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a text view that has id = R.id.myid

```
listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.players_view,
            cursor,
            new String[]{Spray.Columns._ID,Playas.Columns.JOUEUR},
            new int[]{R.id.myid, R.id.nomdujoueur},
            0
    );
```